# Git Submodule fatal reference is not a tree

Tags: git-submodules, git-subtree

Hi I am getting `fatal: reference is not a tree: 947a3c67349eb242a8d46d576e544f8129b28cbf
Unable to checkout '947a3c67349eb242a8d46d576e544f8129b28cbf' in submodule path 'modules/webform'`

My work station is as follows:

```
[root]:
   .gitmodules
   /modules/webform
```

Inside .gitmodules I have:

```
[submodule "modules/webform"]
        path = modules/webform
        url = https://git.drupal.org/project/webform.git
```

I have gone into modules/webform and `git pull` I have also `git submodule sync`, which gives me `Synchronizing submodule url for 'modules/webform'`. I have even hard reset that directory. I was wondering if there is a way to delete that reference/reset to the newest version? when I `git log` it gives me that the reference is a `bad object`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update my `git --version`. I was on 1.7, the latest is 2.1 or something.